# How to bind panels with controls in devexpress docklayoutmanager

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, code-behind, devexpress-wpf

File Name SampleProject
My xaml file Mainwindow.xaml----------

```
<Window x:Class="SampleProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking" Closing="Window_Closing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <dxdo:DockLayoutManager x:Name="docklayoutmanager1" dxdo:RestoreLayoutOptions.RemoveOldPanels="False" dxdo:RestoreLayoutOptions.RemoveOldLayoutControlItems="False" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
        <Button Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" x:Name="ClickMe" Content="Click Me" Click="ClickMe_Click" Margin="323,10,369,729" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`
My xaml.cs file MainWindow.xaml.cs-------------------

```
    using DevExpress.Xpf.Docking;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Layout.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SampleProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(File.Exists("test.xml"))
            {
                docklayoutmanager1.RestoreLayoutFromXml("test.xml");
            }
        }

        private void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var panel = docklayoutmanager1.DockController.AddPanel(DockType.None);
            panel.Caption = "Test Panel";
            panel.Name = "myPanel";
            panel.Content = "I want to serialize this code using guid Please provide example for creating such binding.";
            FloatGroup floatgroup = new FloatGroup();
            floatgroup.Name = "myFloatGroup";
            floatgroup.FloatSize = new Size(500,500);
            floatgroup.FloatLocation = new Point(300, 300);
            floatgroup.Add(panel);
            docklayoutmanager1.FloatGroups.Add(floatgroup);
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlFilePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.xml";
            if (File.Exists("test.xml"))
            {
                docklayoutmanager1.SaveLayoutToXml("test.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                using (File.Create("test.xml")) { }
                docklayoutmanager1.SaveLayoutToXml("test.xml");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a document layout manager programmatically getting panels and controls which is having panels and controls in them.

While saving, I am achieving this with `SaveLayoutToXml()` for my panels and Serializing controls using `bformatter.Serialize();`.

since i have lot of panels and unique controls in them. I want to get the same controls back in same panels as it was before saving and serializing. Please provide me with a code to identify with a unique id for both panels and controls.

And do I have any integer id to which I can assign GUID as BindableName does not work with it.

Thanks
Desh

Comment: can you show your code so far?

Comment: I have done it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create your panels programmatically and and them to your xaml file at run time.

```
 UserC = new UserC();
            DocumentPanel dpanel = new DocumentPanel();
            dpanel.Name = "OpenUC" + count;
            dpanel.Caption = "Open User Control";
            dpanel.BindableName = "OpenUC" + count;
            var content = UserC;
            dpanel.Content = content;
            FloatGroup fGroup = new FloatGroup();
            fGroup.FloatSize = new Size(500, 500);
            fGroup.Items.Add(dpanel);

            DockLayoutManager1.FloatGroups.Add(fGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add a User Control, since nobody seems to be interested in helping, i searched and done something like this:

```
 private FloatGroup CreateDocPanelFloatGroup(DocumentPanel dp)
        {
            FloatGroup floatGroup = new FloatGroup();
            floatGroup.FloatSize = new Size(500, 500);
            floatGroup.Items.Add(dp);

            return floatGroup;
        }

        private void OpenUC_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {         
            openUC = new OpenUC();
            DocumentPanel dp = new DocumentPanel();
            dp.Name = "OpenUC" + count;
            dp.Caption = "Open User Control";
            dp.BindableName = "OpenUC" + count;
            var content = openUC;
            dp.Content = content;
            DockLayoutManager1.FloatGroups.Add(CreateDocPanelFloatGroup(dp));          

        }
```