# Binding DockLayoutManager in xaml with view model file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I want to bind my DockLayoutManager in Xaml with ViewModel. What propert of DockLayoutManager will help me acheve this Binding.`

```
<dxdo:DockLayoutManager  ItemsSource="{Binding DockLayoutManager1,  Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  dxdo:RestoreLayoutOptions.RemoveOldPanels="False" dxdo:RestoreLayoutOptions.RemoveOldLayoutControlItems="False"  FloatingMode="Desktop" Margin="0,54,0,0">
            <dxdo:LayoutGroup>

            </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
```

`

Item Source is not helpin me. while debugging it gives an exception when i add something to docklayoutmanager. Since, DockLayoutManager is NULL. Please provide a solution.

Comment: I think you are using DevExpress Controls. I it's so than look in the Demo-Application for the MVVM Dock Layout Demo.

Comment: I have already tried those examples but since I am having all controls panels dynamic even with caption and content in my ViewModel, I dont want to use this approach. Instead I want add dynamically everything to my docklayout manager as I have shown above. Please provide a code on how tobind docklayoutmanager dynamically with viewmodel so that i can add my panels into it. thanks

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh Are you really talking about MVVM-approach? If so, please provide a code of your View-Model also because it is not quite clear what is the `DockLayoutManager1`. Also, I see from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114323/how-to-bind-panels-with-controls-in-devexpress-docklayoutmanager) and from the worlds "I want add dynamically everything to my docklayout manager" that your current approach is contradict to the MVVM-principles (when using MVVM-approach for creating UI, you should add everything into corresponding View-Model rather than into View).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to use the [ItemsSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ItemsSourcetopic) property for binding dock UI. But you shpuld provide the additional infrastructure from your ViewModel side. For exact solution follow the approaches described in [MVVM Support - Building Dock UI](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11386) article and [How to: Build a dock UI using the MVVM pattern](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3911) example. Please also take a look at the corresponding [product demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/WPF/).

Related articles:
[How to use the IMVVMDockingProperties interface in an MVVM application.](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17270)

JFI - Advanced MVVM concepts (e.g. with Docking UI):
[MVVM Framework](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15112)
[Document Manager Services](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument18171) and [Document Management System](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument18234)
[DockingDocumentUIService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument18275)
[How to: Use WindowedDocumentUIService, TabbedDocumentUIService, DockingDocumentUIService and FrameDocumentUIService](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T211373)

Comment: I have already tried those examples but since I am having all controls panels dynamic even with caption and content in my ViewModel, I dont want to use this approach. Instead I want add dynamically everything to my docklayout manager as I have shown above. 

Please provide a code on how tobind docklayoutmanager dynamically with viewmodel so that i can add my panels into it. thanks

Comment: The [Dock UI example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3911) has already intended for dynamical usage and already contains all the required code. Please review it again - you can just add the specific ViewModel into Workspaces collection dynamically.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh I'm happy to hear that my assistance was helpful (you can accept my answer if it suits your needs)